# Paypal IPN verification always return INVALID status

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-ipn

I hope this can help people with IPN verification... It took a few hours to solve this problem.

I've implemented the IPN validation in Java, but I always was receiving an INVALID response from Paypal server. I think it is a bit confusing, because the same test in the sandbox platform, always returned a PAYMENT_OK status.

After some hours googling, I finally found where was my mistake!

You must set up in your paypal account your default encoding charset  as '**UTF8**', inside 'Selling Preferences' :

1. Log into PayPal
2. Click the ‘Profile’ link in the menu bar under ‘My Account’
3. Click the ‘Language Encoding’ link under the ‘Selling Preferences’ column
4. Click ‘More Options’
5. Set ‘Encoding’ to ‘UTF-8’, and use it for IPN notifications
6. Click ‘Save’

Regards,

Ivan Fontanals